# Translate number to word

Tags: numbers, alphabet

54 needs to be translated into a word. Example hi (in the alphabet h = 8, i = 9,  in the amount of 17. I need, on the contrary, the sum should be 54. I know there will be a lot of words, I need to completely convert the alphabet into numbers and the sum and find it there? How can I do it please?

Just helping,its important